# Pass div id into PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have passed a javascript variable into a div id element in HTML. I am now trying to send that div id to a php variable so I can access it.

However, when I try a POST request it is not grabbing what is assigned to div id. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php 

session_start();

$un = $_POST["result"];
echo "the username is". $un;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>



<script>
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
{
    var getUser = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
} 
else 
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to send the value to the PHP? Nothing on this page is named `hidden-input`, nor is there anything submitting.

Comment: @chris85 I have updated my code in the example.

Comment: `$_POST` is not related to session, that is for `POST` data. Maybe `$_SESSION`, I've never used JS `sessionStorage` though, I'd think that was client side.

Comment: I'm just not sure why it will display the corrent username for <div id="result"></div>      but where I try to access that div id in php it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make a post request you'll need to be using `XMLHttpRequest`. You really should be using a `GET` request  in a separate file, though.

PHP file, named `getId.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_GET["id"];
?>
```

JavaScript code, to retrieve data:

```
var getData = function( url, callback ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        callback(xhr);
    };

    xhr.open( "get", url, true );
    xhr.send();
};

getData('./getId.php?id=' + /* id goes here */, function(json){
    if(json.status == 200){
        data = json.response;
        //Do something with data...
    }
})
```

And finally, to reference the session data, back in the HTML file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "value of username is: " . $_SESSION["id"];
?>
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me! I have updated the HTML to resemble what you have. However, I am still trying to access that variable in the php portion of my code and am unable to do so.

Comment: Are you trying to update the id of <div> or pass the information from <div> to somewhere else? $_POST doesn't read element IDs, it reads query parameters. The id="<?php ?> was a bad edit, i apologize for that.

Comment: i was trying to pass the "result" inside div id into a php variable so I can use that to access the database. div id"results" holds the username that was stored in the javascript sessionStorage.

Comment: I'm not getting a clear idea here. Why are you using <div> in the first place? You don't need any HTML to access the database.

Comment: Ok so,     var getUser = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("username"); uses javascript and stores the username from the login page into sessionStorage, I'm trying to get this into a PHP session so I can access this users profile on the database for their own homepage.

Comment: Updated my answer.